# How to subclass NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, subclass, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need a custom version of `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `sectionIndexTitle(forSectionName:)` and added the following:

```
import CoreData

class FetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
{
    override func sectionIndexTitle(forSectionName sectionName: String) -> String?
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my view controller I had:

```
private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Something> =
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Something>(entityName: "Something")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name",
                                                     ascending: true,
                                                     selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                managedObjectContext: context,
                                                sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionLetter",
                                                cacheName: nil)
    controller.delegate = self

    do
    {
        try controller.performFetch()
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch Somethings: \(error)")
    }

    return controller
}()
```

When I replace `NSFetchedResultsController` with `FetchedResultsController` I get the following error on the first (`private lazy var ...`) line:

```
Cannot specialize non-generic type 'FetchedResultsController'
```

and this error on the creation (`let controller = ...`) line:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<Something>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Define your subclass as generic where the generic type extend the one of the superclass, < ResultType: NSFetchRequestResult>. `class FetchedResultsController< ResultType: NSFetchRequestResult> :NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This resolves the first error, but the second error (`Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<Something>' ...`) remains.

Comment: Try explicitly defining the type of the request variable `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Something> = ...`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks, but doesn't make any difference unfortunately.